# Ngbdatepicker how to select multiple dates and save in array

Tags: angular

```
HTMl - 
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"
                                    [markDisabled]="isDisabled" (dateSelect)="select($event)"></ngb-datepicker>

TS - 

  model: NgbDateStruct;
  date: { year: number, month: number };
  isDisabled = (date: NgbDateStruct, current: { month: number, year: number }) => {
    return this.disabledDates.find(x => NgbDate.from(x).equals(date)) ? true : false;
  }

  disabledDates: NgbDateStruct[] = [
    { year: 2021, month: 8, day: 10 },
    { year: 2019, month: 4, day: 12 },
    { year: 2019, month: 4, day: 14 },
  ]


  select(e) {
    console.log(e, 'eee');
  }
```

I want the dates to get selected as i click on them and then save the dates in array to send it to backend.
Suppose i click on 2/aug/2021, 13th , 20th , etc. These all dates should be selected with different background and get saved in an array.
How can we achieve that with this datepicker. Can someone please help?

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#range, or you want not in series ?

Comment: if so, With (select) and (dateSelect) outputs you'll know which dates are being selected and with the [dayTemplate] input you can customize the way any particular date looks, and store them in an array.

Comment: @Crocsx Not in series. I want to select at random any date. Suppose i select 2/aug/2021, 14/aug/2021, etc. How to customise that they are selected like give some background color for selected date.
And then store these dates in array.

Comment: this is the second reply then. You need to implement you own template for [dayTemplate], and use the (dateSelect) to store those date in an array for exemple, and then just add some custom style to your dayTemplate when selected. Similar to what they do to show week end here : https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/datepicker-customday.ts

Comment: @Crocsx It helped I created template using [dayTemplate] and applied conditions to use. Thanks a lot!!