# How to mark multiple dates on ngx-bootstrap datepicker in angular

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I want to mark multiple date on the ngx-bootstrap datepicker, I tried passing array, it doesn't seems to be working

<ngb-datepicker style="width: 100%;" #dp [ngModel]="allDates" (navigate)="date = $event.next">

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: See if this helps -> [Day display customization](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#day-template)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68936122/ngbdatepicker-how-to-select-multiple-dates-and-save-in-array